# Php Medoo update vs replace

Tags: php, sql, medoo

I do not understand why there is `replace` method in the Medoo class.

What is difference between this and a `update` call?

Comment: I really cannot understand why someone want to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **UPDATE** statement is used to update existing records in a table.
And **REPLACE** method in the Medoo : The replacement value that replaces found search values in a record.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference. Maybe this is a value replace after a select?

Comment: The medoo replace in method is to provide for replace record just like
UPDATE "table" SET your_column = REPLACE("your_column", 'for_replace_val', 'after_replace_val')